# My CSS transition works in only one direction

Tags: jquery, css

I have an animation to shrink my navbar, but it only works on shrink, and not when `.shrink` is removed via jQuery; it gets bigger immediately without any animation. Why?

If I change `min-height` to `height` in both my `.navbar` and my `.navbar.shrink` selectors, it will work. But I need to use `min-height`.

CSS LESS:

```
.navbar{
  min-height: 128px;
  -webkit-transition:  1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
 }

.navbar.shrink{
  min-height: 64px;
  -webkit-transition:  1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
 }
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
 var shrinkHeader = 300;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
      if ( scroll >= shrinkHeader ) {
           $('.header').addClass('shrink');
        }
        else {
            $('.header').removeClass('shrink');
        }
  });
function getCurrentScroll() {
    return window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
  <h1>AnimateFixed Header (Scroll Down)</h1>
</div>
<div class="content">
</div>

<script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please post your related jquery code for removing the class or createa demo http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: What animation do you want, Can you explain it theoritically?

Comment: Which browser are you seeing this issue? I am viewing it on FF and Chrome and I don't see any issues http://jsfiddle.net/73rves1c/

Comment: @Huangism You're using toggle; OP might be removing the class another way.

Comment: @TylerH Yea OP says lost class by jquery, is there a difference between removeClass and toggleClass removal? It's the same behaviour if I use removeClass http://jsfiddle.net/73rves1c/1/

Comment: @Huangism Hmm, I'm not sure. I don't think there should be. I hesitate to say for certain though without seeing OP's jQuery code.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPQVMx

Comment: @TylerH still waiting on OP to post it but transition is defined on shrink and navbar, this code should work as it is given

Comment: @user3202422 I see the transition in FF and Chrome

Comment: @user3202422 Your CodePen works for me in Firefox 35.0.1. What browser and version are you using?

Comment: in this code you can see that when it been bigger - it's immediately. if you replace min height with height it's work in both directions, but I need min-height

Comment: @user3202422 Which browser are you using? Asking for the 3rd time. Because it is working properly in FF and Chrome

Comment: chrome.change height to min-height

Comment: @Huangism I've isolated the issue. If you change `height` to `min-height` in **both**  the `.header` selector **and** the `.header.shrink` selector, you can reproduce the issue. The text still transitions both ways, but the red header element itself changes abruptly on scroll up.

Answer (score 3):

It works but you need to modify your animation accordingly

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwQqGJ

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #cc5350;
    color:#fff;
    z-index: 1000;
    min-height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: min-height 1s;
    -moz-transition: min-height 1s;
    transition: min-height 1s;
    text-align:center;

}
.header.shrink {
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

If you changed to use `min-height` then you need to make sure you are animating `min-height` and not height.

In case you missed it, it's `transition: min-height 1s;` not `transition: height 1s;`

Answer (score 1):

I created a `JSFiddle` example:

**CSS:**

```
.navbar {
     background-color:red;
     height: 128px;
     -webkit-transition: height 0.5s, margin-top 0.5s;
     -moz-transition: height 0.5s, margin-top 0.5s;
     -o-transition: height 0.5s, margin-top 0.5s;
     transition: height 0.5s, margin-top 0.5s;
}

.navbar.shrink {
    height: 64px;
    margin-top: -33px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="primary" class="navbar shrink">  Text </div>
<button id="btn">Add/remove class</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function removeAdd(){
    if($("#primary").hasClass("shrink")){
         $("#primary").removeClass("shrink");
    } else {
         $("#primary").addClass("shrink");
    }  
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').click(removeAdd);
});
```

**URL:** http://jsfiddle.net/67xnkkk8/1/

This works. Use `height` instead `min-height`

Comment: This doesn't make the image bigger or smaller, just the image container. I know OP wasn't talking specifically about an image, but this might still be a little misleading.

Comment: @TylerH I know: I just wanted to introduce some content. The increasing is the `navbar`

Comment: Give it a background colour

Comment: Well currently `'min-height` is working for me even in OP's demo

Comment: Is rare. In my example doesn't work with `min-height`.

Comment: @tomloprod Since OP is slow to respond, what browser are you using where `min-height` doesn't work?

Comment: @TylerH  I use `Chrome 40.0.2214.111` browser.

Comment: Upvoted for a working solution before OP specified the `min-height` "requirement".